# I'm having trouble with adding gameState, I'm supposed to have three gameStates(serve, Play and over) but I only got in serve

Tags: java

I have tried adding the gameStates multiple times, I've also looked at my other codes, and I've referred to many other codes I've found online

```
var playerGoal = createSprite(200,28,100,20);
playerGoal.shapeColor = ("yellow");
var compGoal = createSprite(200,372,100,20);
compGoal.shapeColor=("yellow");
var striker = createSprite(200,200,10,10);
striker.shapeColor = "white";
var playerMallet = createSprite(200,50,50,10);
playerMallet.shapeColor = "black";
var computerMallet = createSprite(200,350,50,10);
computerMallet.shapeColor = "black";
var boundary1 = createSprite(200,145,400,5);
boundary1.shapeColor = "white";
var boundary2 = createSprite(200,250,400,5);
boundary2.shapeColor = "white";
var boundary3 = createSprite(200,385,400,5);
boundary3.shapeColor = "white";
var boundary4 = createSprite(200,15,400,5);
boundary4.shapeColor = "white";
var boundary5 = createSprite(10,200,5,400);
boundary5.shapeColor = "white";
var boundary6 = createSprite(390,200,5,400);
boundary6.shapeColor = "white";
var gameState = "serve";
var gameState = "end";
var compScore = 0;
var playerScore = 0;


function draw(){
  background("green");
 
  
  //gamestate serve
  if(gameState === "serve"){
    text("PRESS SPACE TO STRIKE",140,180);
     textSize(50);
  fill("black");
    
    if(keyDown("left")){
      playerMallet.x = playerMallet.x - 10;
    }
    if(keyDown("right")){
      playerMallet.x = playerMallet.x + 10;
    }
    if(keyDown("up")){
      if(playerMallet.y > 25)
      {
        playerMallet.y = playerMallet.y - 10;
      }
      
      if(keyDown("down")){
        if(playerMallet.y<120)
        {
          playerMallet.y = playerMallet.y + 10;
        }
      }
    }
    
  
  }
   text(compScore,20,230);
   text(playerScore,20,180);
  

  for (var b = 20; b < 400; b=b+20)  {
    line(0+b,200,10+b,200);
  }
  if (keyDown("space")) {
    serve();
   
    gameState = "play";
    
  }
  
 
  
  
  
  
  if(striker.isTouching(playerGoal) || striker.isTouching(compGoal)){
  if(striker.isTouching(playerGoal)){
    compScore = compScore +1;
     
  fill("black");
    reset();
  }
  
  if(keyDown("r") && gameState === "over"){
    gameState = "serve";
    compScore = 0;
    playerScore = 0;
  }
  
  if(striker.isTouching(compGoal)){
    playerScore = playerScore+1;
     textSize(50);
  fill("black");
    reset();
  }
    gameState = "serve";
    reset();
  }
  
  
  
  
  if(keyDown("left")){
    playerMallet.velocityX = -5;
    
  }
  if(keyDown("right")){
    playerMallet.velocityX = 5;
    
  }
  if(keyDown("up") && playerMallet.y > 25){
    playerMallet.velocityY = -5;
    
  }
  if(keyDown("down") && playerMallet.y < 120){
    playerMallet.velocityY = 5;
  }
  
 
  
  
  if (keyDown("space") && gameState === "serve") {
    serve();
    gameState = "play";
  }
  
 
  if(playerScore === 5 || compScore === 5){
    text("GAME OVER",170,165);
    text("PRESS 'R' TO RESTART", 140, 185);
     textSize(50);
  fill("black");
    gameState = "over";
  }
  
  if(gameState === "over"){
    reset();
    
  }
  
  if(keyDown("r") && gameState === "over"){
    gameState = "serve";
    compScore = 0;
    playerScore = 0;
  }
  
  
  
  
 
  computerMallet.x = striker.x;
  drawSprites();
  }


function serve(){
  striker.velocityX = 5;
  striker.velocityY = 5;
}

function reset(){
  striker.x = 200;
  striker.y = 200;
  striker.velocityX = 0;
  striker.velocityY = 0;
  playerMallet.x = 200;
  playerMallet.y = 50;
  playerMallet.velocityX = 0;
  playerMallet.velocityY = 0;
}
```

Even though I have added the gameStates and used conditional programming to tell the computer what to do it's showing me errors, I have checked my previous codes and asked my teacher and a friends and family, it's still not working, when doesn't show any error there is no difference in the output.